# How to get all data from parent table with checking child table relationship where condition in laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables Leads and Tasks, I need to fetch all leads by checking one specific column in the tasks table.

Laravel
Mysql

Relation on Lead Model

```
 public function tasks()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Task::class, 'lead_id', 'id');
}
```

[leads table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5SBL.png)

[tasks table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPBrw.png)

*need to list all leads which create_task_id != 2 (tasks table)

Comment: Can you share us what are the columns of `Leads` and `Tasks` table?

Comment: Sure.I will add table details to my question

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check relation condition you should use `whereHas()` method.

```
Load::with('task')->whereHas('task', function ($query){
        $query->where('some condition')->get();
})->get();
```

Comment: I am already tried out whereHas(), its only return the data which have the relation